# Batoo support for Amazon RDS, S3 and MySQL

Tags: jpa, batoo

I was wondering if it supports Amazon RDS, and S3.

Furthermore, I would like to find documentation regarding the level of support given to MySQL joins, but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance, Pedro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batoo supports MySql as a first class citizen including joins. As Batoo JPA is a pure spec implementation, It will produce SQL joins of inner and left joins according to the Jpa fetch and fetch types.

For the amazon support, it should just work. You can follow the compatibility test case from https://github.com/BatooOrg/BatooJPA/issues/187

Edit: RDS is same as the DB provider software used so it supports RDS

Comment: Oh boy, oh boy, so Batoo works with all the complex joins and RDS? Thanks, this is what I wanted to hear! karma++